# Parent poms seperated by concerns? (Test config, deploy config)

Tags: java, maven, configuration

I am just studying parent poms as we currently don't use them yet and have to reconfigure testing and deployment for every project again.

My first shot was a company-parent pom which contains:

- Testing config (surfire plugin with unit and integration test config)
- Deployment config (javadoc, source creation and deployment to local nexus)

Today I thought, that I actually could split this up into two poms (and concerns). Each would only have a configuration about one topic, which would lead to a modular configuration, that would work like:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mycompany.parent</groupId>
          <artifactId>testing-pom</artifactId>
          <version>0.2.0</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mycompany.parent</groupId>
          <artifactId>deployment-pom</artifactId>
          <version>0.2.0</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

The improvements of splitting up are, that I simply can import the capability I need.

As I haven't never seen this anywhere yet, is it discouraged to do so?

Comment: Why are configuring those things such in a different way? So surefire plugin for unit tests which are defaults of maven-surefire and Maven...furthermore integration tests should be handled by maven-failsafe-plugin and never by maven-surefire-plugin...and what kind of configuration do you mean? Can you give an example? It looks like you are going the wrong path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating 2 dependancies parent you're using a BOM, and as far as i know plugins are not inherited with BOMs. i don't know if you want to do that way but you have to handle plugins in children files.

Comment: Yes you are actually right. I assumed this would work but the plugins are  not getting executed this way. I'll restrict to one parent pom. Thanks for you helpful first contribution :)